Creating a notification channel: required Context but found String
I'm trying to create a notification channel with some help from this tutorial (on creating notifications) and this tutorial (on creating alarms). I have this code:
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    val channel = NotificationChannel(Notification.CATEGORY_REMINDER, "Reminder to Edit Trip", importance).apply {
        description = "Send half-hourly reminders to edit the details of a trip."
    }
    val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager //TODO
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}

I don't know how to write the TODO line since I get the error "Required: Context, Found: String". The first tutorial wrote it as:
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class)

which doesn't work because I get an error on NotificationManager saying "Classifier NotificationManager does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialised here", and the second tutorial wrote the line as:
private val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)

which also doesn't work because of an error on context saying "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied".
I found this SO question on the same issue, but the answer no longer works since context no longer has getSystemService(). I tried both
val notificationManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) 

which gives the error "Unresolved reference: getSystemService()"
and
val notificationManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

which gives the error "Required: Context, Found: String".
So how can I write this now? I'm targeting API 30.

You can't directly use context outside of Fragment. You have to pass reference or use requireContext() if it's fragment or use this if it's service or activity. To give a detailed answer, you need to provide us with complete codes of what you are trying to do.

Where have you put this logic? Inside of an activity/viewmodel/fragment/service?

@tomerpacific In my main activity, which is a ComponentActivity.

I figured it out (though don't really know the theory on why it works): we get the context via LocalContext.current, which then requires the function to be a composable. This would then require my calling function, onCreate() to be a composable, but that would clash with @SuppressLint and @OptIn, so I had to call the function from setContent(). Here's the entire code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WayToGoTheme ( content = {
                Scaffold {
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    val application = context.applicationContext as WayToGoApplication
                    val routeRepository = application.routeRepository
                    val waypointRepository = application.waypointRepository
                    val routeViewModel: RouteViewModel = remember { RouteViewModel(routeRepository) }
                    val waypointViewModel: WaypointViewModel = remember { WaypointViewModel(waypointRepository) }
                    val navController = rememberNavController()

                    CreateNotificationChannel()

                    NavGraph(navController = navController, waypointViewModel = waypointViewModel, routeViewModel = routeViewModel)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun CreateNotificationChannel() {
    val ctx = LocalContext.current

    // Use LaunchedEffect to ensure the side effect happens only once
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(Notification.CATEGORY_REMINDER, "Reminder to Edit Trip", importance).apply {
            description = "Send half-hourly reminders to edit the details of a trip."
        }
        val notificationManager = ctx.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

